# avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer error

Tags: uploading

When I try to upload I get this error. I cannot upload the program into my Arduino Mega ADK board. I tried putting the drivers agiain too, but it does not work.

```
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
```

Is it the problem with the hardware or the system?
Please help me. Thank you :)

Comment: See [Have I bricked my Arduino Uno? Problems with uploading to board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board/) and [What happens when code is uploaded using the bootloader?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/15936/what-happens-when-code-is-uploaded-using-the-bootloader/). I'm going to close this question. Thanks for your understanding and cooperation!

Answer (score 1):

I get this problem sometimes with some of my boards. I usually solve the problem following these steps:

- Set the compiler on debug/verbose mode to see what's happening
- Launch compilation/upload
- When the compile phase is done, and the upload process is about to start, press the reset button on the board

Usually that takes care of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What @dda says in his answer are good points.

Removing the board USB for a few seconds, then re-plugging and re-selecting the COM port in the IDE usually fixes it.  Sometimes when you un-plug and re-plug the board it changes COM ports.

Also if you have a short-circuit wired to your arduino sometimes it becomes non-responsive in this manner.